# C# Visual studio - Import new downloaded project to my current project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, import, using

I downloaded a new compression algorithm Zstandard from GitHub and I want to use it (refference it with using directive).
https://github.com/bp74/Zstandard.Net

But I dont know how can I add it in my project, since it's not through Nuget, which is very easy to use, I simply dunno how to add it.

Please help

Comment: You can compile it, grab the dll(s) and add them to your project. Or, just add existing project to your solution and make a project reference. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't/don't want to use the NuGet link from the bottom of the page you've linked? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zstandard.Net/

Comment: You'll find all you need here to add a project to the solution and reference if from another to run: [Learn about projects and solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions) & [Manage references in a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I want to use a bit different version of zstd that is not on NuGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded it as a source, you need to compile it first: add the project file to your solution Zstandard.Net/Zstandard.Net.csproj (you probably do not need to add the other projects). Right click compile to check whether you can compile it.

Then go to your project/References, right click, add reference, Projects -> check the Zstandard.Net project.

From this point on you can reference the namespace via using directive.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Right click on your solution >> Add >> Existing Project
Navigate to the project file (.csproj file) >> Open

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your solution >> Add >> Existing Project Navigate to the project file (.csproj file) >> Open